Replace deprecated NavigationView for iPhone and iPad Layout
I'm currently using NavigationView to layout my App for iPhone and iPad depending on the horizontalSizeClass. Since the functions I'm using for NavigationView and NavigationLink are deprecated I wonder if one can achieve something similar with the latest APIs.
Here is the simplified version.
ContentView
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) private var horizontalSizeClass

    var body: some View {
        if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
            iPhoneEntry()
        } else {
            iPadEntry()
        }
    }
}

AppItems
indirect enum AppItem: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int {
        hashValue
    }

    case foobar, profile, welcome, articles, books, websites
    case nested(item: AppItem, nested: [AppItem])

    @ViewBuilder
    var destination: some View {
        switch self {
        case .foobar:
            FoobarOverview()
        case .profile:
            Profile()
        case .welcome:
            Welcome()
        case .articles:
            Overview(navTitle: "Articles")
        case .books:
            Overview(navTitle: "Books")
        case .websites:
            Overview(navTitle: "Websites")
        case .nested:
            EmptyView()
        }
    }

    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .foobar:
            return "Foobar"
        case .profile:
            return "Profile"
        case .welcome:
            return "Welcome"
        case .articles:
            return "Articles"
        case .books:
            return "Books"
        case .websites:
            return "Websites"
        case .nested(let item, _):
            return item.name
        }
    }

    static var ipad: [AppItem] = [.welcome, .profile, .nested(item: .foobar, nested: overviews)]

    static var iphone: [AppItem] = [.welcome, .profile, .foobar]

    static var overviews: [AppItem] = [.articles, .books, .websites]
}


iPhone Layout
struct iPhoneEntry: View {

    @State var selectedItem: AppItem? = .welcome

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedItem) {
            ForEach(AppItem.iphone) { item in
                switch item {
                case .foobar:
                    NavigationView {
                        FoobarOverview()
                    }
                    .tag("Overview")
                    .tabItem { Label("Overview", systemImage: "circle") }
                case .profile:
                    Profile()
                        .tag("Profile")
                        .tabItem { Label("Profile", systemImage: "triangle") }
                case .welcome:
                    Welcome()
                        .tag("Welcome")
                        .tabItem { Label("Welcome", systemImage: "square") }
                default:
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

iPad-Layout
struct iPadEntry: View {

    @State var selectedItem: AppItem? = .welcome

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(AppItem.ipad) { item in
                    if case .nested(let item, let subItems) = item {
                        Section {
                            ForEach(subItems, content: ListItem)
                        } header: {
                            Text(item.name)
                        }
                    } else {
                        ListItem(item)
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.sidebar)
            .modifier(ColumnModifier(appItem: selectedItem))
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.columns)
    }

    func ListItem(_ appItem: AppItem) -> some View {
        NavigationLink(tag: appItem, selection: $selectedItem) {
            appItem.destination
        } label: {
            Text(appItem.name)
        }
    }

    private struct ColumnModifier: ViewModifier {
        let appItem: AppItem?

        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            if appItem == .welcome || appItem == .profile {
                Group {
                    content

                    Text("Select something")
                }
            } else {
                Group {
                    content

                    appItem?.destination

                    Text("Select something")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Dummy Views
struct Profile: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Profile")
    }
}

struct Welcome: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Welcome")
    }
}

struct FoobarOverview: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(AppItem.overviews) { item in
                NavigationLink(item.name, destination: item.destination)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Overview: View {

    var navTitle: String

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ... 10, id: \.self) { num in
                NavigationLink("\(navTitle) number: \(num)") {
                    Detail(title: "\(navTitle) number: \(num)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Detail: View {

    var title: String

    var body: some View {
        Text("foobar")
    }
}

EDIT:
I want to know how I can navigate 6 levels deep for iPad and iPhone without implementing two layouts.

Can you describe the iPad design in words? The view should normally be two-columns, but you want an extra column to appear when one of the overviews is selected. Did I understand correctly?

@Sweeper The iPad Layout should have depending on the appitem 2 or 3 column layout. Since NavigationView was deprecated my assumption is that I have to use NavigationSplitView to have 2 or 3 Column layout for iPad. Is this assumption correct?

@Sweeper sorry my question was kind of fuzzy about what I want to know. I updated my question.

You might be better off letting SwiftUI select the UI for each platform for you and just remove that if. For navigation items that don't replace the detail level you can use .isDetailLink(false)

NavigationSplitView cannot have a dynamic number of columns, and I don't think NavigationView officially supported this anyway.
That said, you can achieve a similar kind of behaviour by wrapping two NavigationSplitViews with an if. i.e. show the three-column split view if the selected item is one of the ones in AppItem.overviews, otherwise show the two-column split view.
struct iPadEntry: View {

    @State var selectedItem: AppItem? = .welcome

    var body: some View {
        if let selectedItem, AppItem.overviews.contains(selectedItem) {
            NavigationSplitView {
                SplitSidebar(selectedItem: $selectedItem)
            } content: {
                SplitDetail(selectedItem: selectedItem)
            } detail: {
                NavigationStack {
                    Text("Select something")
                }
            }
        } else {
            NavigationSplitView {
                SplitSidebar(selectedItem: $selectedItem)
            } detail: {
                NavigationStack {
                    SplitDetail(selectedItem: selectedItem)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SplitSidebar: View {
    @Binding var selectedItem: AppItem?
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selectedItem) {
            ForEach(AppItem.ipad) { item in
                if case .nested(let item, let subItems) = item {
                    Section {
                        ForEach(subItems) { subItem in
                            NavigationLink(value: subItem) {
                                Text(subItem.name)
                            }
                        }
                    } header: {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                } else {
                    NavigationLink(value: item) {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.sidebar)
    }
}

struct SplitDetail: View {
    let selectedItem: AppItem?
    var body: some View {
        if let selectedItem {
            selectedItem.destination
        } else {
            Text("Select something")
        }
    }
}

That said, I would recommend redesigning this to not use a dynamic number of columns. Consider navigating to the overview view in the same column, or nest another two-column split view in the detail column.
Here are the other views:
struct iPhoneEntry: View {

    @State var selectedItem: AppItem = .welcome

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedItem) {
            ForEach(AppItem.iphone) { item in
                switch item {
                case .foobar:
                    NavigationStack {
                        FoobarOverview()
                    }
                    .tabItem { Label("Overview", systemImage: "circle") }
                case .profile:
                    Profile()
                        .tabItem { Label("Profile", systemImage: "triangle") }
                case .welcome:
                    Welcome()
                        .tabItem { Label("Welcome", systemImage: "square") }
                default:
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

struct FoobarOverview: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(AppItem.overviews) { item in
                NavigationLink(item.name) { item.destination }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Overview: View {

    var navTitle: String

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ... 10, id: \.self) { num in
                NavigationLink("\(navTitle) number: \(num)") {
                    Detail(title: "\(navTitle) number: \(num)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Side note: you should declare AppItem.id as:
var id: AppItem { self }

Do not use the hash value as an identifier (for anything), because hash collisions exist.

So I would need need to use NavigationStack for iPhone and NavigationSplitView for iPad?

@Carsten You have a TabView for iPhone, don't you? There is a NavigationStack in the tab view, yes. What is your point?

using NavigationSplitView for iPad is limited to 3 columns. Assuming there is another NavigationLink in Detail(...) there will be no back button

@Carsten That's easy to fix. Just surround the detail views with NavigationStack too. See the edit.
